Szegő's inequality
I know Erdős-Lax's inequality and a couple of proofs. It states that:
If $P(z)=\sum_{v=0}^{n} a_{v} z^{v}$ is a complex polynomial of degree $n$ having no zeros in $|z|<1$, then
$$
\max _{|z|=1}\left|P^{\prime}(z)\right| \leq \frac{n}{2} \max _{|z|=1}|P(z)|.
$$
There is a weaker one, which I think is attributed to Szegő. It states that:
If $P(z)=\sum_{v=0}^{n} a_{v} z^{v}$ is a complex polynomial of degree $n$ having all its zeros on the unit circle, then
$$
\max _{|z|=1}\left|P^{\prime}(z)\right| \leq \frac{n}{2} \max _{|z|=1}|P(z)|.
$$
Here are my questions:

Is this correctly attributed to Szegő?
If so, do you have a reference?
I am looking for a simpler/shorter proof than Erdős-Lax's (which obviously implies Szegő's).


A polynomial $P(z) = \sum_{v=1}^n a_v z^v$ satisfies $P(0) = 0$.
Do you mean $\sum_{v=0}^n a_v z^v$?

Indeed, thanks @NoamD.Elkies. Typo fixed.

You may like to check references given in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernstein%27s_theorem_(polynomials)

Thanks @MaxAlekseyev This reference talks about Erdős-Lax's but not Szegő's inequality, or am I missing something?

@Portland: there are other references like Malik (1969) and more recent ones, but I did not check if they are relevant to your question.

p. 510 of Lax's paper seems to give Szegő's proof in full detail

Indeed, thanks a lot @MaxAlekseyev

I also meant thanks @OtisChodosh
